# Bash loop to remove files matching name structure

Tags: bash, file, loops, terminal

Using a bash loop, I want to remove one of three types of file names in a folder

1) L4.mp3

2) L4 withMusic.mp3

3) L4 noIntro withMusic.mp3

There are many files of these three types and the only thing that changes is the number after L

I want to: 
**Keep** any files with names like **1** (the original file)

**Keep** any files with names like **3** (music added and intro removed)

But **Remove** all files with names like **2** (music added but not intro)

What is the best way to do this?

My initial idea (which didn't compile anyway) was:

```
for file in *.mp3; do
name=${file%%[.]*};
if name !=  "$*trimmed wMusic.mp3";
then
rm file;
fi
done
```

but output was:

```
-bash: name: command not found

-bash: name: command not found

-bash: name: command not found

-bash: name: command not found
```

Comment: Bash does not compile.  Ever.  So you probably received an error message on terminal, please add it to the question.  While you are adding this, please format the code portion (use the `{ }` icon in the editor).

Comment: `rm *"noIntro withMusic.mp3"` ?

Comment: Use [Python](https://python.org).

Comment: @funky-future That would be great. How would I do this in Python?

Comment: The syntax for if statement should be `if [ "$name" == "$somevariable" ]`

Comment: perhaps you are trying to use `rm "$name"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why will you need the loop but here are some suggestions:

```
ls *.mp3 | grep '(1)' | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

this will get all the .mp3 files that have the expression (1) in them e.g. abc(1).mp3 etc

if you want to have a broader reach or more dynamicity in your approach I will recommend using regex in grep:

```
ls *.mp3 | grep -P "regex-here" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

if you want to delete few other type of files e.g. mp4 etc as well in the same command then use:

```
ls *.{mp3,mp4,mpeg} | grep -P "regex-here" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

you can also use regex and delete with the help of **find**:

```
find -iregex 'regex-here' -delete
```